# Is there a PHP function that adds backslashes to Bash command line special characters?

Tags: php, bash

The function `addslashes()` only prepends bashslashes to the single quotes, double quotes, backslashes and the NULL byte.

Is there a function that returns a string with backslashes before any Bash special character?

For example

`$escaped = foo ('Led Zeppelin Discography (Complete)/[1969] Led Zeppelin I');`

`echo $escaped;` would print the following:

`Led\ Zeppelin\ Discography\ \(Complete\)/\[1969\]\ Led\ Zeppelin\ I`

Comment: It's really called `addslashes()`, not `addbackslashes()`.  Hmm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`escapeshellcmd()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php) escapes any characters in a string that might be used to trick a shell command into executing arbitrary commands.

```
string escapeshellcmd ( string $command )
```

Also, take a look at [escapeshellarg()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php)